# Tunnel NETCONF for dynamic host over SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a requirement to tunnel NETCONF (typically TCP-22) connections over a jumphost, but for a dynamic host.

I understand I can do remote SSH tunneling for defined hosts, e.g.:

```
ssh -R 2201:jumphost:22 rtr1
ssh -R 2202:jumphost:22 rtr2
```

But I'd like to be able to connect to a dynamic host, by tunneling over a jumphost, something like:

```
ssh -R 2201:jumphost:22 *
```

And then to be able to make a NETCONF connection such as:

connect rtrN port 2201

Is this doable via SSH tunneling? I don't want to use dynamic SSH tunnels, as I'd have to specify a proxy port whenever I make the connection, which I can't really do when I make the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually figured out how to do this in case anyone is interested:

In SSH config file:

```
Host *.*
        ProxyCommand ssh user@jump nc %h %p
```

Then anything you SSH to, will forward over the jump connection, then `nc` to the host.